# Set the popup window to center jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

Right now I'm setting the position of the modal jQuery window in this way:

```
   var winH = $(window).height();
   var winW = $(window).width();
    //Set the popup window to center
    $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
    $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);
```

How do I center the popUp when I scroll down?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could just use another CSS style, try `position: fixed`

Answer (score 6):

you can use this in this way

// Position modal box in the center of the page

```
    jQuery.fn.center = function () {
    this.css("position","absolute");
    this.css("top", ( jQuery(window).height() - this.height() ) / 2+jQuery(window).scrollTop() + "px");
    this.css("left", ( jQuery(window).width() - this.width() ) / 2+jQuery(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
    return this;
  }
```

//then call the function

```
 jQuery(".modal-profile").center();
```

and this will make your code organized and easy to use in any project for center the modal. you can view this kind of work in another question

[modal appears on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370906/modal-appears-on-page-load/10370949#10370949)

Answer (score 4):

This one is helped me!

```
$.fn.center = function() {
    this.css("position", "fixed");
    this.css("top", ($(window).height()/2 - this.height()/2) + "px");
    this.css("left", ($(window).width()/2 - this.width()/2) + "px");
    return this;
}
```

And use as described.

> $(".modal-window").center();

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the jQuery UI Dialog, [the default position is 'center'](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-position) which centers it in the viewport by default. If you're using a different jQuery modal window, then:

```
$(id).css({
    'position': 'fixed',
    'top': parseInt((winH / 2) - ($(id).height() / 2), 10)
    'left': parseInt((winW / 2) - ($(id).width() / 2), 10)
});
```

might do the trick. I'm not sure what you mean by "scroll down" as a modal dialog and scrolling (outside the dialog) are mutually exclusive.