# modal appears on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

Following is my code but the modal only appears when someone click on

```
<a href="#" rel="modal-profile">open modal box</a>
```

I want to know how can i modify my following code so that my modal appears on the page load.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery.noConflict();

    // Position modal box in the center of the page
    jQuery.fn.center = function () {
        this.css("position","absolute");
        this.css("top", ( jQuery(window).height() - this.height() ) / 2+jQuery(window).scrollTop() + "px");
        this.css("left", ( jQuery(window).width() - this.width() ) / 2+jQuery(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
        return this;
      }

    jQuery(".modal-profile").center();

    // Set height of light out div  
    jQuery('.modal-lightsout').css("height", jQuery(document).height());    

    // Fade in modal box once link is clicked
    jQuery('a[rel="modal-profile"]').click(function() {
        jQuery('.modal-profile').fadeIn("slow");
        jQuery('.modal-lightsout').fadeTo("slow", .5);
    });

    // closes modal box once close link is clicked, or if the lights out divis clicked
    jQuery('a.modal-close-profile, .modal-lightsout').click(function() {
        jQuery('.modal-profile').fadeOut("slow");
        jQuery('.modal-lightsout').fadeOut("slow");
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    color:#333;
    background-color:#ec176c;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
}
.modal-profile h2 {
    font-size:2em;
    letter-spacing:-1px;
}
.modal-profile {
    display:none;
    height: 250px;
    width: 500px;
    padding:25px;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px #292929;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px #292929;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px #292929;
    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    z-index:50;
}

.modal-lightsout {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:25;
    background:#000;
}

a.modal-close-profile {
    position:absolute;
    top:-15px;
    right:-15px;
}

a.modal-social {
    margin:0 10px 0 0;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="modal-lightsout"></div>
<div class="modal-profile">
    <h2>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend</h2>
    <a href="#" title="Close profile window" class="modal-close-profile"><img border="0px" src="close.png" alt="Close profile window" /></a>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<a href="#" rel="modal-profile">open modal box</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like bellow

```
function modalload(){

jQuery('.modal-profile').fadeIn("slow");
jQuery('.modal-lightsout').fadeTo("slow", .5);
}
```

and call this in your page load like bellow

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

modalload();

});

and then your modal will appear after page load. you can also load the modal after some time of the site load by calling timer function.

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: i am not able to change font family now why so in h2??

Comment: you can show the link. may be you made any kind of jquery error so you didn't able to change font by jquery. will you show in detail.s

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('.modal-profile').fadeIn("slow");
jQuery('.modal-lightsout').fadeTo("slow", .5);
```

Place the above in [.ready](http://jqapi.com/#p=ready) for document

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
         jQuery('.modal-profile').fadeIn("slow");
         jQuery('.modal-lightsout').fadeTo("slow", .5);
    });
```

This way your methods to show modal box will happen as soon as the document is ready

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/r7Yrn/)**

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

To make it load on only page load, just remove the click handler, like so:

```
jQuery('.modal-profile').fadeIn("slow");
jQuery('.modal-lightsout').fadeTo("slow", .5);
```

To keep the click handler, and still make it open on page load, just trigger a click, like so:

```
jQuery('a[rel="modal-profile"]').click(function() {
    jQuery('.modal-profile').fadeIn("slow");
    jQuery('.modal-lightsout').fadeTo("slow", .5);
}).click();
```

Just add the `.click()` at the end of your function, at it will run on page load.